# A journal appeared indexed until 2016 is now cancelled in Scimago. What does this mean?

Tags: databases

In some online databases such as DBLP some journals or conferences appear that are canceled or not appear at all after a few years. For what I know that is because, according to DBLP, the mentioned conference does not uphold with some criteria of quality to continue to appear on that database.

In Scimago, I have seen that a journal appeared indexed until 2016, but now it appears a message saying "Cancelled", what does it mean apart of the obviousness of that message? maybe that the journal has become a predatory one? or that it quality has decreased?

Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Scimago seems to draw from Scopus' journal coverage (according to its [About Us](https://www.scimagojr.com/aboutus.php)-page):

> The SCImago Journal & Country Rank is a publicly available portal that includes the journals and country scientific indicators developed from the information contained in the Scopus® database (Elsevier B.V.).

Scopus regularly re-evaluates its journals. It even offers an Excel-list of recently discontinued journals ([at the bottom of this page](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/how-scopus-works/content)).

In that list, you can see the column `Reason for discontinuation` (column F). This should at least provide a vague keyword as to why a given journal was cancelled.

It seems that there are four such reasons:

- "**Metrics**" (under-performance of a journal)
- "**Publication concerns**" (I see journals from predatory publishers like OMICS who carry that reason).
- "**Radar**" (outlier performance; "an algorithm that flags journals based on approximately 40 outlier predictors, including sudden change in output volume, sudden change in publishing country and/or affiliations, and high journal/author self-citation rates" -- [citation from this F1000 article, at p. 14](https://f1000researchdata.s3.amazonaws.com/manuscripts/28667/bf914aa9-0f40-4453-bee4-baf57eaf92b9_23847_-_andrea_cortegiani_v2.pdf?doi=10.12688/f1000research.23847.2&numberOfBrowsableCollections=27&numberOfBrowsableInstitutionalCollections=5&numberOfBrowsableGateways=27))
- "**do not meet Scopus criteria**" (probably refers to Scopus' [journal selection criteria](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/how-scopus-works/content/content-policy-and-selection), e.g. peer reviews, lack of publication delays, editorial board diversity, online availability of articles etc. As [this Scopus blog post](https://blog.scopus.com/posts/is-a-title-indexed-in-scopus-a-reminder-to-check-before-you-publish) indicates, some journals are indeed simply discontinued by the publisher, which might fall under this reason.)